# adding a small API to a web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application with some standard routes, and I would like to add some API endpoints into it.

I figure I just have to add some routes (probably under a `scope '/api'`), create some new controllers that extend `ActionController::API`, and then perhaps do something so rails magically knows how to render the JSON data.

Are there any guides on how to do this? Everything I can find talks about creating 'API only' applications, but doesn't discuss adding a few API endpoints to an existing web application.

edit: I am specifically looking for rails 5 solutions

Comment: How on earth does this have only 316 views and previously 0 upvotes? Blows my mind. Such a good and widely applicable question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between a "classical" or API only application are pretty small. The API only app scales away some of the middleware and components that are not needed in an API.

Otherwise the steps of building the actual API components are pretty much identical.

You will want to start by choosing a different superclass for your API controllers. Your API controllers don't need all the junk on ApplicationController and you will be treating quite a few aspects such as authentication differently.

Rails 5 has `ActionController::API`, In previous versions you would use `ActionController::Metal` and include the modules needed.

```
# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
class ApiController < ActionController::API
  # Do whatever you would do in ApplicationController
end
```

You then setup your routes:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  resources :things
end
```

And controllers:

```
module API
  class ThingsController < ApiController

    before_action :set_thing, except: [:create, :index]

    def show
      render json: @thing
    end

    def index
      render json: @things = Thing.all
    end

    def create
      @thing = Thing.create(thing_params)

      if @thing.save
        head :created, location: [:api, @thing]
      else
        render json: @thing.errors, status: :bad_entity
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

There are quite a few aspects to building an API such as versioning and JSON serialization strategies and you'll find plenty of tutorials on the subject - just don't get hung up on the API only part.

Comment: how does the `ApiController` above live alongside my existing `ApplicationController`? How does rails know to look at it?
edit: is it because of the `namespace`?

Comment: Because you set your api controllers up to inherit from ApiController instead of ApplicationController. There is nothing magical about ApplicationController in Rails. Its just a class that the rails generators set controllers up to inherit from. I realize that I forgot to add `< ApiController` in the example - I hope its more clear now.

Comment: oh wow I see, I think that may have been the missing piece... Im on my phone now but will come back to this later today and close this off, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Decide on an API data format (in this case we'll use JSON)
2. Figure out what your endpoints will be (for example let's say you're creating a `products#create` endpoint)
3. Decide on an API scoping and versioning scheme (in this case `v1`)
4. In your `config/routes.rb` add the routes seen below
5. Create a directory in your controller directory named `v1`
6. Create a controller in that `v1` directory like the one below

   ```
   #goes in routes
   namespace 'v1', defaults: {format: 'json'} do
     resources :products, only: [:create] 
   end

   #controller
   module V1
     class ProductsController < ActionController::API

       def create
         #some code
       end
     end
   end
   ```

**Random Wisdoms**

- Try to think about your end point as thoroughly as possible. I don't know if you're planning for someone to consume this API or if you will be the only person using it but think about each end point from the perspective of what will be consuming it; this will save you lots of refactoring and redesign time.
- You should also look into the pattern of using serializers to help with you object decoration before serving them to your endpoints.
- Make sure that you think about how you want handle errors, do you want them to fail silently, do you want to give feed back to the consumer etc. Whatever you choose to do just make sure you're consistent.

Look here for some advice:

https://www.codementor.io/franzejr/creating-simple-api-with-rails-du108148l

https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application

Comment: This does not answer the question. Its just some random wisdoms.

Comment: Hi, thanks but these seem to be for rails 4 (or at least, less than rails 5) and don't actually address adding an API to an existing application

Comment: Yea I am actively editing sorry the rails 5 comment was not there when I started answering.

Comment: just to clarify, I dont know the specific steps to making it so the controller returns JSON data - I get the routes, and I assume I can create a controller by going `rails g controller my_thing` and manually changing the base class to `ActionController::API` but how do add an action that returns JSON data?

Comment: (I know conceptually what an API is and how to design one, but not how to _create_ one in my existing rails application)

Comment: Yea I was having some formatting issues , this is a basic way to add a simple API to an existing rails app.

Answer (score 0):

use something like

`namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do`

to default your api controllers to only render json.

the rest of what you described is a decent implementation and is exactly what we use in production today. some endpoints are still plain rails, but most are api json only with client side MVC doing the heavy lifting. this is a common use case when migrating from default rails apps to client side MVC.

another good gotcha to have is base your api controllers of a base api controller that you create, which inherits from application controller.